# Radio stream inside the html VS. javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, audio

Which way is better and more preferred over the other?

Both are using 2 different methods.

Are there any advantages or disadvantages of using either?

**Code 1**

https://jsfiddle.net/juw4kbap/225/

```
  function playAudio(player, button) {
    player.volume = 1.0;
    player.setAttribute("src", "http://hi5.1980s.fm/;");
    player.play();
  }
```

VS.

**Code 2**

https://jsfiddle.net/juw4kbap/170/

```
 function playAudio(player, button) {
    var src = button.getAttribute("data-audio");
    player.volume = 1.0;
    player.setAttribute("src", src);
    player.play();
  }
```

Comment: Both are inefficient, the second one is a little worse off because it gets it's src from a div that sits right next to the blank audio tag. So there's one trip to the function then from there to be loaded then played. The first one has the src in the function and so there's less travelling around. Performance wise there's no difference because it's purpose is simple. It may look big and complex, but it's just big and clunky.

Comment: @zer00ne Thank you for your response. What would be a better way to do it?

Comment: That's too broad for a question to be answered.here. Click on my icon then search my answers. Almost all of my answers are pretty detailed.